# jQuery Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question related to the jquery Uploadify plugin because I am not sure I understand the documentation.

Please look here http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/ at the onComplete event. It says there are arguments sent to that function including the response argument.

How can I access those arguments? If I do alert(response) that doesn't work. Here's a little snippet:

```
$('#photo').uploadify({
    'uploader'       : '/flash-uploader/scripts/uploadify.swf',
    'script'         : '/flash-uploader/scripts/upload-public-photo.php',
    'cancelImg'      : '/flash-uploader/cancel.png',
    'scriptData'     : {'user_id' : 'USER_ID'},
    'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
    'auto'           : true,
    'multi'          : true,
    'sizeLimit'      : 2097152,
    'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
    'wmode'          : 'transparent',
    'onComplete'     : function(response) {
        alert(response); // doesn't work
        // but docs say response argument is sent to this function...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is just the text output by the upload script according to [here](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=572). So most likely, the upload script just isn't outputting anything.